# Ajax, I want use a search box in my layout view, but it fails when I am not on the "home/index"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This script runs inside of file entitled otf.js. The form listed below run in the _layout.cshtml in the shared folder. This script will execute without any problem on the main website page but any other page it will not redirect the user. I did use fiddler2 to see if the ajax was returning information and found that it did recover the data but it will not redirect and pass the data to the main page.

```
$(function () {
    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {

        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function(data) {

            var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
            $target.replaceWith(data);


        });
        return false;
    };

    var submitAutocompleteform = function(event, ui) {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.val(ui.item.label);
        var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
        $form.attr("action", "/home/index"); // doesn't work on other pages
        $form.submit();

    };

    var createAutocomplete = function() {
        var $input = $(this);

        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete"),
            autoFocus: "true",
            select:  submitAutocompleteform

        };
        $input.autocomplete(options);
    };

    var getPage = function() {
        var $a = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $a.attr("href"),
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            type: "get"
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function(data) {
            var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-otf-target");
            $(target).replaceWith(data);
        });
        return false;
    };


    $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
    $("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
    $(".main-content").on("click", ".pagedList a[href]", getPage);

});
```

my form in the my layout view of my website:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" method="get"
                    data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#restaurantList" >
                    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete","Home")"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
                </form>
```

The autocomplete gets the list of restaurants but will not redirect me back to the /home/index/ and save what i am looking for.

Comment: Hi, you forgot part of your post: "my form in the my layout view of my website" is blank. Make sure you also include a well-defined question *in your post*, not just in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this ajax function work seamlessly, I need to have the div that housed that results in the body surrounding JUST the @RenderBody() and seen below:

```
    <div id="body">            
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <div id="restaurantList"> 
            @RenderBody()
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I did try this in this in the past but my problem became that the pagedlist function, would not work. that is because of the code listed below:

```
    $.ajax(options).done(function(data) {
        var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-otf-target");
        $(target).replaceWith(data);
    });
    return false;
};
```

Essentially the code was finding the parents of the div with the attribute "data-otf-target" and replacing it. This error would only take place on the other pages because the other pages was not calling a partial view to render a list of restaurants. Therefore, I needed to make sure that div named, "restaurantList", was being recreated when the autocomplete ajax was used and a user click one of pagedlist icons.

I did this by replacing that ajax code with this:

```
    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-otf-target");
        $(target).replaceWith("<div id='restaurantList'>" + data + "</div>");

    });
```

Thank you for looking and thank you for all the helpful edits.